# Is there a delay for receiving certain earned hats?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, winterbash

I was checking out the [hat selection](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/) today and noticed the following requirement for the Defender of the Realm hat:

> at least 5 flags dismissed as helpful and at most 20% of non-disputed
>   flags declined

Since the event started, I've raised 10 flags, with 100% of them marked "Helpful" (So 0% declined). Yet this hat is still locked for me.

Is there a delay for this and/or some other hats?

Comment: I'm not positive about this, but my guess is that flags that you raise to close questions must not be counted in the algorithm. Perhaps it's because they are not directly handled by moderators, but instead go into the /review queue.

Comment: @eldarerathis interesting. Either way, the hat did eventually come - albeit I can't figure out exactly why it came so late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so many other things on Stack Exchange (especially badges) I expect that hats are not awarded instantly, but rather there's a scheduled process that runs to find new hats to award.

You'll probably get it in the next few hours, assuming that there's not some other criteria that needs to be met.

Comment: One day later, still a no-show, while another hat was awarded almost immediately after its conditions were cleared.

Comment: I'd call it a bug, then, unless there's some criteria not being met that we're not seeing. Hopefully a dev will pop in here and clear it up.